# How to convert MD5 back to image?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I found this `crypto` package and it's really amazing for what it does.

I've now accomplished on how to convert ***images*** to ***MD5*** which is what I'm sending to the database.

Now my problem is I'm fetching those images back as MD5 and I can't show them as `Image`.

I have an idea wherein I should use `Image.memory` which accepts `Uint8List bytes`.

I've also seen that my MD5 image has a function `.bytes` (e.g. `myMD5Image.bytes`) which is being accepted by `Image.memory` (e.g. `Image.memory(myMD5Image.bytes)` )

but it gives an error:
**`Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.`**

I would like to ask for suggestions or possible solutions to this. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is a part of my code when a user draws in the canvas

```
  generateSignature() async {

    if (_controller.isNotEmpty) {
      var data = await _controller.toPngBytes();
      var signatureMD5 = md5.convert(data);
      print("BYTES : $data");
      print("MD5 : $signatureMD5");
      print("BACK TO BYTES : ${signatureMD5.bytes}");

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: Dialog(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                //SHOWS IMAGE
                Image.memory(
                  data,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                ),
                //DOESNT SHOW IMAGE
                Image.memory(
                  signatureMD5.bytes,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: I've edited my post. =)

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a hashing function, so once you apply it to your data, it is not reversible. MD5 (or SHA-1, Whirlpool, etc.) is therefore not suited for your use case.

A typical use of hashes is to store user credentials in a database. Instead of having passwords in clear, you want to store its hash so that when a user authenticates themself, the platform generates a hash of the password entered by the user and compares it with the hash stored in the database. If it matches, then the password is correct yet it remains hashed in the database.

Here are some encryption algorithms that you can use instead:
https://blog.storagecraft.com/5-common-encryption-algorithms/